# How to get clicked item in view

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I am a relative beginner in django. In one of my templates, I am creating a list of items stored in a database. With the following `template.html` **code**:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
       <li>
          {{ item.name }}
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Rendering from `views.py` **code**:

```
def category_view(request):
    list = Category.objects.order_by('name')
    context = {'items': list}
    return render(request, "template.html", context=context)
```

Now, I want to get the name of the **list item (category)** on which the user has clicked, so that I can show user **sub-categories** on the next page depending on what was selected on the previous page.

Kindly share ideas of how to get the clicked item and flow to send dependent list to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

{{ item.name }} should be a link to a subcategory_view's path. So user will be redirected to your subcategory page.

Comment: Thank you, can you share little bit more detail about how to link?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user by clicking to item's subcategory_view. So, your list may have links with `item`'s id (or slug). Like that:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
       <li>
          <a href="/items/{{item.id}}">{{ item.name }}</a>
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```